# Are questions about App Review on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Today I encountered [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251233/apple-rejected-my-app-twice-citing-a-very-grey-area-violation-but-already-hav) pertaining to "unfair treatment" by the App Store Review, and whether the OP should "appeal" the decision for his app to be rejected.

Is this kind of question on- or off-topic on this site?

Comment: Great question and good link. The first thing [we need to do is a light edit for generality and get the right tags on the post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/251233/revisions) - iTunes-connect is the service that should be tagged on all those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Somebody treated me such-and-such, what should I do" is practically always off-topic. OTOH, the linked question can be turned into a "what options do I have if this-and-this fails" question with a small edit which is on-topic usually.

Comment: That's what I tried to do with my answer, provide options and direction for both the OP and others who might feel the same.  I hope that was the correct thing to do.

Comment: I liked your answer :-)